# improve video quality in ExoPlayer

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I am sure that ExoPlayer supports a setting for improving video quality.
But I don't know how to do this in the coding.
If anybody is experienced in doing so, could you please teach me?

Answer (score 1):

First of all what video are you playing? Is it local video or from web, and what format of it?

From my experience it is possible that you set something wrong and video is just not getting adjusted(if it is about video from web, hls format for example).

Comment: Live stream videos are from remote server and file extension is ts.